# Cin until end of input

Tags: c++, loops, cin

I need to read in a string and then an integer until the user indicates end of input (ctrl-d in linux).  Again, I am stuck.  Currently I have a while loop:

```
while (getline(cin, line))
```

However, that gives an entire line and then I cannot seem to separate the string from the integer.  Suggestions would be most appreciated!  :)

Comment: What constitutes a "string" in the input? A single word, or a phrase with multiple words? I.e. is "George Bush 43" valid input, or must it be "George-Bush 43"?

Comment: while(cin>>mystring>>myint) {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the string and the integer is separated by whitespace;
Do this:

```
while(std::cin>>your_string>>your_num>>std::ws){}
```

You can choose your own delimiter, by writing a manipulator yourself.

Another approach would be to do it your way, and put the input line into a stringstream and extract the string and numbers from it. That approach seems roundabout to me as you get strings from a stream only to put it into another stream.

Comment: Thank you!  This forum is better than my teacher!  I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: `>>std::ws` is not necessary. The next input will eat all of the intervening whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin>>a
```

The above statement reads a token from standard input and stores it in the a variable. What is less known is that it also returns a bool value. When you reach the end of all standard input, the above statement would return false.
Use it in an if statement!

```
if(c>>a){
  cout<<"End of standard input has been reached!";
}
```